# Logging to file from alternate view within theme - Orchard CMS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.7

How do I access the Orchard logger from an alternate so I am able to insert an entry into the logs stored within Orchard.Web/App_Data/Logs/... The location of my alternate is within a theme.

I am currently using the following code which is not writing to the log files.

```
@using Orchard.Logging
@{
    try {
        throw new Exception("This is an error");
    } catch (Exception ex)
        var logger = NullLogger.Instance;
        logger.Error(ex, "Alternate error");
}
```

I realise that it's not ideal to be doing this from an alternate, happy to hear other methods as long as my initial question is answered first.

Comment: Why do you want to do that in first place? Error handling logic is not a view responsibility. This should happen in the controller. Anyway - the above won't work for sure. `NullLogger.Instance` is just a placeholder that does not do any actual logging.

Comment: When an exception occurs within an alternate the site simply shows a blank white "screen of death", and nothing reported in the error logs. I would like to wrap a try statement around some simple logic in my alternates and if an error is thrown, log what it so the problem can be easily diagnosed and resolved. Although this is not ideal, it's better than nothing.

Comment: Have you confirmed that the error is not in the action/driver? If there is an issue Orchard just won't render the item. There should not be anything in the view to cause the error. Consider changing the output view model to be more complete, so that there is no business logic in the view. It might help to show the code for the driver/view in question.

Comment: The alternate is created through the shape tracer and creates the cshtml file within my theme, so the action/driver is core Orchard code. An example of when the 'blank white screen of death' happens is accessing a field which does not exists in a object of dynamic type.